# Ubuntu boot error rootdevice

Tags: boot, initramfs

So, what is this error that comes when i started to boot ubuntu 14.04.
How to solve this?

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:    
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)    
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)    
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)    
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/4e2e4952-f2b0-4458-afe4-22f8cbe53ac1 does not exist.    
Dropping to a Shell!    
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)    
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.    
(initramfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem few weeks ago.
In the busybox, can you mount your disk ?
if 'yes', your disk is still seen by the system.

execute the following:

```
sudo blkid
```

it will display the uuid's of your disks. check that they are ok with the grub file.

Try rebooting on an older kernel via grub, it should boot.
Then, in a shell, execute :

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot again on the newer kernel, it should be ok.